# Strange behaviour with image input in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have an issue with my current web project. I need to check if my request contains an input called *image*, so I just apply the normal method like so:

```
if($request->has('image'))
{
    ...
}
```

But for some reason, this is not working as shown below:

[image: laravel]

Can someone explain me why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to access uploaded files as,

```
 $request->hasFile('image');
```

then it should be

```
if($request->hasFile('image')) { ...
```

see this [DOC](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#files)